# image file can not found or does'nt exists in django

Tags: python, django

I am using `django 1.11`.

I cannot display my image file to the page; it say

```
media/products/file-name  does not exits
```

but i checked, my `MEDIA_URL` and `MEDIA_ROOT` are correct.

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS =[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static_my_proj")
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "workspace/static_cdn", "static_root") 
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "workspace/static_cdn", "media_root")
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from app import views
from products.views import (
    ProductListView,
    ProductDetailView,
    ProductFeaturedListView,
    ProductFeaturedDetailView,
    ProductDetailSlugView,
)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.home_page, name='home'),
    url(r'^contact/$', views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^login/$', views.login_page, name='login'),
    url(r'^register/$', views.register_page, name='register'),
    url(r'^product/$', ProductListView.as_view(), name='product'),
    # url(r'^product/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^product/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', ProductDetailSlugView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^featured/$', ProductFeaturedListView.as_view(), name='featured'),
    url(r'^featured/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ProductFeaturedDetailView.as_view(), name='fdetail'),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_URL)
    urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_URL)
```

**models.py**

```
def get_filename_ext(filepath):
    base_name = os.path.basename(filepath)
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(base_name)
    return name, ext

def upload_image_path(instance,filename):
    new_filename = random.randint(1,2324324423)
    name, ext = get_filename_ext(filename)
    final_filename = '{new_filename}{ext}'.format(
        new_filename=new_filename, ext=ext)
    return 'products/{new_filename}/{final_filename}'.format(
        new_filename=new_filename, final_filename=final_filename)

class ProductManager(models.Manager):
    def featured(self):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(featured=True) 

class Product(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length = 120)
    slug        = models.SlugField(blank=True) 
    description = models.TextField()
    price       = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, default=39.99)
    image       = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image_path, null=True, default=True)
    featured    = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = ProductManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://ecommerce-hk967144.c9users.io/media/products/1299799540/1299799540.jpg
Raised by:  django.views.static.serve
"/media/products/1299799540/1299799540.jpg" does not exist
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to be in your settings as far as I can see. If you look at the [docs for `static()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#static) you can see that you need to use `STATIC_ROOT` and `MEDIA_ROOT`, but you use `*_URL` twice instead of using `*_ROOT`.

Change these lines

```
urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_URL)
urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_URL)
```

to this

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

But, the use of `static()` is only necessary if you do not have `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`; if you do have it in your `INSTALLED_APPS`, then remove these two lines.

---

Furthermore:

- you should not use a `float` for the default value of your `DecimalField`; use `Decimal('39.99')` instead (add `from decimal import Decimal`).
- you should not use `default=True` for your `ImageField`, because `True` is not a valid image.

Comment: yeah your answer work. .problem is exact you say i put double *_URL twice instead of ROOT. .very big thanks to you. .